# Problems with making scale_colour_manual work for my multi-factor bargraph on ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

I am trying to make a manual colour scale for my bar graph using plyr to summarize the data and ggplot2 to present the graph.

The data has two variables:

1. Region (displayed on the X-axis)
2. Genotype (displayed by the fill)

I have managed to do this already, however, I have not been able to find a way to personalize the colours - it simply gives me two randomly assigned colours.

**Could someone please help me figure out what I am missing here?**

I have included my code and an image of the graph below. The graph basically has the appearance I want it to, except that I can't personalize the colours.

```
ggplotdata <- summarySE(data, measurevar="Density", groupvars=c("Genotype", "Region"))
ggplotdata
#Plot the data
ggplotdata$Genotype <- factor(ggplotdata$Genotype, c("WT","KO"))
Mygraph <-ggplot(ggplotdata, aes(x=Region, y=Density, fill=Genotype)) + 
     geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity",
           colour="black",
           size=.2) +
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Density-se, ymax=Density+se),
           width=.2,
           position=position_dodge(.9)) +
     xlab(NULL) +
     ylab("Density (cells/mm2)") +
     scale_colour_manual(name=NULL,
           breaks=c("KO", "WT"),
           labels=c("KO", "WT"),
           values=c("#FFFFFF", "#3366FF")) +
     ggtitle("X") +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:17*500) +
     theme_minimal()
Mygraph
```

[image: Image of graph]

Comment: As you are using `fill` in the `aes`, you have to use `scale_fill_manual` instead of `scale_color_manual`

Comment: thank you for your help! It works now!

Comment: @Liptongal If you have answered your question, remember to add the response and marked as resolved. So in the future, if someone had the same issue, he would be able to find the response.

Comment: @GermanQuinteros How exactly do I do that ? Sorry this is my first question.... I can only see the flag icon next to dc's response...

Comment: @Liptongal add an answer. After that on the left top of your answer, you will see a tick grey if you click it, it will be changed to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here was to use scale_fill_manual instead, thank you @dc37